# WebBrowser, IPersistStreamInit and javascript

Tags: delphi, winapi, webbrowser-control

For one of our desktop applications we use a HTML-based interface, loaded from local files into a WebBrowser control.

This works fine, but now we want to load the files from a different source, and are trying to stream them in using IPersistStreamInit (like this example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752047(VS.85).aspx)). It seems to work OK, except for the referenced javascript .js files (JQuery et al). It tries to load those from the "about:" location resulting in errors.

What I would really like is to get a callback event whenever additional files are streamed, and substitute the right data. That might be asking for a bit too much though, so suggestions for workarounds are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Call `CreateURLMoniker()` to obtain an `IMoniker` interface, load your HTML data into it via its `Load()` method (which takes an `IStream` interface as input), and then you can use the browser's `IPersistMoniker` interface instead of its `IPersistStreamInit` interface to process the data.  The URL you pass to `CreateURLMoniker()` will be used as the base URL.

Comment: I have now created a custom IMoniker implemementation, that loads my own data in the BindToStorage() method. Using IPersistMoniker my content now gets loaded, and TWebBrowser looks for additional files (javascript, images, etc) at the GetDisplayName() URL. Which is nice, but doesn't quite solve my problem yet: I need to provide the data for those additional files myself. Unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a lightweight custom protocol handler using an [Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767916(VS.85).aspx), which would give a callback for files.

I have some demo code at http://www.jasontpenny.com/blog/2010/03/23/custom-protocol-handler-in-delphi/